# Unloaded N-type FET has same voltage on drain and source in OFF state

Tags: voltage, troubleshooting

I have two FETS where FET 1 has its drain connected to a voltage supply and its source connected to a common leg, and FET 2 has its drain connected to the common leg and its source connected to a voltage divider. The thought was that by applying a voltage to the gate of either fet, the common leg can function as a voltage supply or a connection to the voltage divider.

When everything is connected, the drain and source for both fets becomes equal to the supply voltage. I have begun to suspect this is because there is no load, but dont understand why this would be the case? Are drain and source not isolated when there is no voltage on the gate (gate voltage = 0)?

Here is the circuit:

[image: At steady state VPIN = V+ = VDIV when both VG1 = VG2 = 0]

Here is a full implementation of the circuit, I want to use it for detecting shorts. I would apply voltage to the gate of one branch and connect a FET to V+, simultaneously apply voltage to the gate of one fet to connect the other branch to the voltage divider, then look for a signal at the voltage divider. If a short is not present Rs would be an open circuit, but if there is a short then Rs would function as a resistor between 12 and 400 ohms.

[image: full implementation]

Comment: What MOSFETs are you using? And which nodes exactly measure what voltage? What's the voltage across "R" when this happens? What are the gates connected to?

Comment: @JonathanS. Using PJC7404_R1_00001 N channel mosfets. When VG1=0=VG2 and V+=3.3V, VPIN and VDIV both equal 3.3V. VDIV is 3.3 and ground is ground, so R is dropping 3.3V. Gates are connected to GPIO extender MCP23017 which talks with a raspberry pi.

Comment: Are the various VG voltages connected directly to ground or do they happen to be floating? The circuit itself looks fine to me as long as you drive the gates properly. Could you show us a picture of the physical circuit? Do you have a solid ground connection between your circuit and the Pi?

Comment: @JonathanS. Unfortunately I have the board on a pcb so routing would be really difficult to see (bad for prototyping :/). Right now the pullups are disabled on the pins so they could be floating. On my scope I see 0V coming from the MCP23017, but I will enable the pullups. I am sure my ground is good as well.

Comment: With pullups enabled the circuit behaves the same, unfortunately

Comment: You can check whether the pins are floating by measuring them against +3.3V. If they're floating, the multimeter's input resistance will pull them to +3.3V and you'll read 0V on the multimeter. Also, try turning the entire circuit off and measure the drain-source resistance of your MOSFETs.

Comment: What is the value of R? I assume all 4 FET have been killed via cross conduction.

Comment: @Jens Value is 1kOhm, should limit current to orders of mA